# Oauth Login is not working - Redirect too many times (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

I have a facebook login button with this route:

```
<a href="{{route('social.auth',['provider' => 'facebook'])}}"  

style="background-color: #3b5998; color:white;"> 
 <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Login</a>
```

When the button is clicked the user is redirected to "[http://proj.test/auth/facebook/callback?code=...*=*](http://proj.test/auth/facebook/callback?code=..._=_)"

But it appears an error:

```
Page is not working, proj.test redirect too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.
```

Do you know where can be the error?

**Routes:**

```
Auth::routes();


Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@redirectToProvider',
    'as'   => 'social.auth'
]);

Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' =>   'OauthController@redirectToProvider',
    'as' => 'social.auth'
]);
`
```

**OAuthcontroller:**

```
class OauthController extends Controller

{
    public function redirectToProvider($provider)
    {
        return Socialite::driver($provider)->redirect();

    }
    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

        return $user->getEmail();

        // $user->token;
    }
}
```

**In the App domains I have:**

```
proj.test
```

**In the site url:**

```
http://proj.test/
http://proj.test/facebook/auth/callback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning you have:

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@redirectToProvider',
    'as'   => 'social.auth'
]);

Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' =>   'OauthController@redirectToProvider',
    'as' => 'social.auth'
]);
```

That's why you get the `Page is not working, proj.test redirect too many times. ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.` exception. User was redirected to the provider login page and after sucessfull login he goes back to the... redirectToProvider! In seconds and subsequences calls redirectToProvider you already was successfully logged so the login windows doesn't appears and provider (facebook) instantly redirect back to the redirectToProvider method and story repeats as longs as browsers throws the exception.

As @btl mentioned you have 2 equal routes, so you changed it to:

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@redirectToProvider',
    'as' => 'social.auth'
]);

Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@handleProviderCallback',
    'as' => 'social.auth'
]);
```

Now you have 2 routes which points to redirectToProvider and handleProviderCallback methods, but... the handleProviderCallback override the first route. You **cannot define 2 routes with same method** (get in this case) **which share the same uri**. Change first one to e.g. `auth/{provider}`. In the second one remove the `'as' => 'social.auth'` part (**route name must be unique**).

In consequence when you click login button you goes to the handleProviderCallback and Scialite detects that state is not valid, that's why you get `Laravel \ Socialite \ Two \ InvalidStateException No message` exception. In redirectToProvier method Socialite store state value in session and pass it to the provider via `?state=...` query param. After successfully login facebook redirect to the callback url with the same state you passed in the redirectToProvider method (implemented under the hood). Socialite compare the state retrieved from the provider with the state stored in the session and throws an above exception if states are different. Because you go directly to the handleProviderCallback you get the empty state value which will never match the one stored in the session (even if session is empty).

Correct routes:

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@redirectToProvider',
    'as' => 'social.auth'
]);

Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@handleProviderCallback',
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of your routes are pointing to the `redirectToProvider` method. Change

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'OauthController@redirectToProvider');
```

To

```
Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', 'OauthController@handleProviderCallback');
```

Comment: Thanks. I change the routes to "Auth::routes();


Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' => 'OauthController@redirectToProvider',
    'as'   => 'social.auth'
]);

Route::get('auth/{provider}/callback', [
    'uses' =>   'OauthController@handleProviderCallback',
    'as' => 'social.auth'
]);" but when the login button is clicked the user goes to "http://proj.test/auth/facebook/callback" but it appears an error "Laravel \ Socialite \ Two \ InvalidStateException
No message"..